# XPath for RadioButton with INPUT tags inside a DIV class

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, automation

I have below code I need to select a radio button based upon the Button label adjacent to the radio buttons:

```
<div class="formclassname">
<input name="radiobutton" type="radio" class="classname">
</input>
"BUTTONLABEL"
</div>
```

Solutions used, but not working:

```
xpath="//input[@name='radiobutton']//parent::div";
xpath="//div[@class='formclassname' and contains(.,'BUTTONLABEL')]";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably being tripped up by the fact that your text contains quotes. If you are trying to select the `<input>` element, try something like:

```
//div[@class='formclassname' ][contains(.,"BUTTONLABEL")]/input[@name='radiobutton']
```

That should output:

```
<input class="classname" name="radiobutton" type="radio">
```